# Firebase load related data iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

What's the best way to load "related" data in swift?

Common setup, if I have a list of users all stored under `uid` node and contains a list of `follows` which stores uids, something like:

`"users" : {
    "abc123" : {
      "email" : "test@test.com",
      "follows" : {
        "xyz789" : true
      }
    },
    "xyz789" : { ... }
}`

What's the most efficient way of loading in the data for all the users one user follows? Is it best to loop through each of the `uid`'s with `observeSingleEvent(of: .value)`?

This is the solution I've come up with, but feels somewhat cumbersome:

```
func loadRelated(user: User, completion: @escaping (Bool, [UserObject]) -> ()) {

  let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users/" + user.uid + "/follows")
  ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in

    var uids = [String]()
    for child in snapshot.children {
      let userData = child as! DataSnapshot
      uids.append(userData.key)
    }

    let userRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users")
    var users = [UserObject]()
    var count = 0
    uids.forEach { uid in
      userRef.child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
        let user: UserObject(from: snapshot)
        users.append(user)
        count += 1
        if count == uids.count {
          completion(true, users)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't really want to go down the denormalization path and store each users data under the top level user.

Answer (score 1):

If you are decided on using Realtime Database, it is best practice to create another root node in your case called `user-follows`. You can create a follow at the path `user-follows/$uid/$fid` by setting the value to `true`, then on your app you would have to `observeSingleEvent` for each snapshot key (`$fid`) at `user-follows/$uid`.

To avoid having to observe each follow separately, instead of setting the value to `true`, you can just store the data you need about a user in `user-follows/$uid`. However, a user may change their username for example and so you would need to keep the data inside each `user-follows` up to date. You can utilise Firebase Cloud Functions to maintain the `user-follows` when a user changes their information.

Otherwise, I would suggest looking at [Firebase Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), where some nesting is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that your node at */users* will always contain few users, you could try to get all the users at once with a `observeSingleEvent(of:)` at path */users*. Then filter the users with the ones who are in *../follows*.
This may pull more data but it might be faster (not sure) and will need less code to handle.

In fact your initial implementation is quite performant already. Just make sure to handle correctly failing of `observeSingleEvent(of:)` or the condition `count == uids.count` will never be fulfilled.

By the way storing each user under *../follows* will just duplicate your data and will be hard to maintain updated. So yes avoid it.